# Action property is null in message request in rest service C#

Tags: c#

I have a REST service in C# as shown below :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/GetData"]
    [OperationContractAttribute(Action = "urn:crud:insert/IService1/GetData")]
    string GetData(string value);
}
```

When I send my custom header details to `ServerMessageInspector`, then I am always getting action property as null

```
public class StringTrimmingMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request,
        IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        if(request.Header.Action!=null) // Issue : this property is always null
        {
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
{
}
```

Would you please help or suggest me how can i set this property, same example works fine when i use WCF service but my requirement to use REST service only.

Comment: REST services are usually called **without** any extra headers that would point to action. Such headers on the other hand are common for SOAP services. Looks like you are mixing two different approaches, combining a REST service and expecting the client to send the action name in the header. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Consider using ASP.NET WebApi for implementing a REST based API. It is far easier than using WCF.